# How to get value of test_layer0_input in conv_net_sentence.py?

Tags: python

I am working on 'Sentence classification using CNN' and referring this code:

https://github.com/yoonkim/CNN_sentence

I want to see the input matrix which is a sentence in this case. Can anyone tell me how to check that value? I think we can get this value from this variable (test_layer0_input). Am I right, please correct me.

Comment: You might want to (re)read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your question would look better if you would include at least the relevant parts of the code.